# Cannot decompile a JAR file

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I found a really strange JAR file. It contains two classes. I tried every single decompiler I know, even IntelliJ's Fernflower. All of them gave me this result: [Screenshot of IntelliJ's decompiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIL5r.png)
When I try to view the bytecode of the class, I can see some weird stuff aswell: [Screenshot of ASM Bytecode Viewer in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnvhJ.png)
It says that the class is "synthetic". I looked up what it means in google and I really have no idea how such a class can be considered synthetic. Any ideas how this is made and how it's possible to replicate such a thing?

Comment: This is apparently an obfuscated JAR.

Comment: This apparently an obfuscated Minecraft mod. Since you can't manage to decompile it, it seems they've succeeded in their obfuscation.

Comment: I am aware that this JAR is obfuscated, but I am not sure how such an obfuscation is done and I am asking in case anybody knows and can help me to replicate this in my own Minecraft mods, since I do mods aswell in my free time and I wanted to know if its possible to replicate this obfuscation for my mods.

Comment: That byte code looks quiet normal to me, except that someone flipped the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` bit in the access flags. It’s funny that this is already enough to make decompilers fail so badly…

Answer (score 0):

The synthetic flag is used to mark classes/fields/methods/... that have been generated by the compiler and did therefore not exist in source code. (see [`JVM-spec 4.1-B`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-E.1))

Since you've added the `java-bytecode-asm` i guess you want to know how to achieve this using the objectweb asm library.
It is done by setting the `ACC_SYNTETHIC` flag for the class.

Here is a class visitor that does it for the class and all fields and methods:

```
public class MakeSyntheticVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    public MakeSyntheticVisitor(int api, ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
        super(api, classVisitor);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        super.visit(version, access | Opcodes.ACC_SYNTHETIC, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }

    @Override
    public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, Object value) {
        return super.visitField(access | Opcodes.ACC_SYNTHETIC, name, descriptor, signature, value);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        return super.visitMethod(access | Opcodes.ACC_SYNTHETIC, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
    }
}
```

Let's use our visitor to transform a class:

```
public static void main() throws Exception {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("in/Test.class"));

    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);

    cr.accept(new MakeSyntheticVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7, cw), 0);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("obfuscated/Test.class"));
    out.write(cw.toByteArray());
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the most cases you are not allowed to decompile software. In this case I'm pretty sure you are not allowed, because the class name was *obfuscated*. But the strange @thingys are properly some type of [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) or custom `Annotation` from a libary

**Edit:**
It is a `Annotation` of minecraftforge. Here is some information on it: https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/structuring/#what-is-mod

*Please do not decompile sourcecode you dont own!*

Comment: Supposedly it's allowed for interoperability

Comment: Does not seem like it is the case, but I'm not as much into that topic as you seem to be

Answer (score -2):

Using classes from [ObjectWeb ASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM)

```java
{
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("in/Test.class"));

    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);

    cr.accept(new MakeSyntheticVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7, cw), 0);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("obfuscated/Test.class"));
    out.write(cw.toByteArray());
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: @Abra There is no `MakeSyntheticVisitor` in ASM. This code also does not decompile anything.